# Integrate the Dirichlet distribution over finite intervals of each random

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Is there a close form solution for the integration of the dirichlet distribution over finite intervals of each random variable set up over the simplex. For example

$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}  \frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1\right)\Gamma\left(\alpha_2\right)\Gamma\left(\alpha_3\right)}x_1^{\alpha_1-1}x_2^{\alpha_2-1}(1-x_1-x_2)^{\alpha_3-1} \rm \, \, dx_2 \, \rm dx_1.$$

If not, how do you use montecarlo or numerical ways to integrate the integral.

Comment: In it's current form, this is not a valid definite integral of the Dirichlet distribution. To make it valid, you need to add the constraint $0 \le 1-x_1-x_2 \le 1$ to ensure that the third component of the probability vector is a valid probability. In practice, you might want to constrain $x_3=1-x_1-x_2$ further by providing a lower limit greater than 0 or an upper limit less than 1, say $x_3\in[e,f]$. Do this by including an indicator function in the integrand, $\mathbb{1}_{[e,f]}(1-x_1-x_2)$.